# Center image that is bigger than the screen

Tags: css

I attached a drawing of what my page looks like. The page has a width of `980px` and the image has a width of almost `1200px`. What I want to achieve is to have the page centered and to show as much of the image as possible while also keeping the image centered. I tried to absolutely position the image but then on mobile devices the browser page is set to the width of the image and the content does not stay centered.

Basically, there could be screens where not the entire image is shown to the user but only as much as fits the screen.

CSS:

```
.page_container {
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.image {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="page_container">...</div>
<div class="image"><img .../></div>
<div class="page_container">...</div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using media queries?

Comment: do you have to use an image? you can use a background image in the body an center it

Comment: @NathanLee no, I don't

Comment: What is the width of the screen you are using? If the screen's width is 1200px, then it will absolutely position the image to that width - not the width of the container it's in.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909940/why-does-overflowhidden-prevent-positionsticky-from-working) might help

Answer (score 3):

pls use the position: relative for the image.like this:

```
<div class="page_container">...</div>
<div class="image"><img src="http://g.hiphotos.baidu.com/album/w%3D210%3Bq%3D75/sign=3584477cf636afc30e0c386483229af9/caef76094b36acaf18169c407dd98d1000e99c93.jpg" width=1200 height=200 /></div>
<div class="page_container">...</div>
```

css code:

```
.page_container {
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
  background: orange;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -600px;
}
```

the margin-left is equal to the　img's width/2. pls view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/jklya).

Comment: this would be perfect if it shortened the image both from the left and the right and not only from the right.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try This

```
 <div class="popup">
 <div class="wrapper">
 <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/8826906676_501192b1c4.jpg">
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.popup{
position:fixed;
left:50%;
}
.popup .wrapper{
position:relative; 
left:-50%;

/*popup-styles*/
background-color:#fff;
padding:10px;
border:solid 2px #444;
border-radius:10px;
}
html{background-color:#aaa;}
```

Example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ62f/33/)

[by Elad Shechter](https://coderwall.com/p/quutdq?i=9&p=1&q=author%3aelad2412&t%5B%5D=elad2412)

Comment: this kinda does what I want, except that I don't want the image to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
.image {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-600px; // half of image width
}
```

Comment: this keeps it left aligned and only makes it smaller from the right

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="img/img.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.image').each(function() {
          var imageSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
          $(this).css('background', 'url(' + imageSrc + ') center top no-repeat');
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper .image img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to center `<img />` tag.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.warpper img {
display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<div class="warpper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkOwi.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is a soltution, only thing is that it won't work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/squadjot/hva34oju/

HTML:

```
    <div id="imgwrap">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkOwi.jpg">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #imgwrap {
      text-align:center;
    }
    
    #imgwrap img {
      margin:0 -1000%; /* don't ask :P */
    }
```

Works in every browser i've tried. IE, Chrome, Opera, FF

Answer (score -1):

> background-size:auto;

set this property for your image

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
  .image {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%; 
  }
```

I think it will work for bigger images...

Answer (score -1):

> .image {
>       position: absolute;
>       left: -50%;    }

Comment: this only makes it smaller from the right side, while keeping it at the same position on the left