# A large table with horizontal scroll and sticky header

Tags: css, html, flexbox, css-grid

**What I am trying to do**

I want to use `thead th {poistion: sticky; top: 0}`. But that [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909940/why-does-overflowhidden-prevent-positionsticky-from-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) with `overflow: scroll`. My table content is very wide so I do need some kind of scrolling. Instead, I have removed the `overflow: scroll` and plan to use the native window scroll.

**Problem**

This works great and the header is actually sticky. However, upon scrolling right, header and footer remain left aligned. This makes sense as I would expect it to do this. But it makes my page look really ugly when someone scrolls horizontally.

**Here is an example**

```css
header {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
}

table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>Navigation and Header</nav>
</header>
<main>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

**What I want instead**

As you can see, the header stays where it is. What I would like to do is at least have the background of header and footer extend all the way to the right. I don't mind if the content is still on the left but the background is set to white which is really ugly.

Is there a way to do this with CSS Grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I would like to do is at least have the background of header and footer extend all the way to the right.

You can do this by simply applying a `display: grid` declaration to the `body` element.

There's no room for the `body` element's child elements to share space horizontally, so those elements will be automatically flowed into a column in which they all share the same width.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
}

header {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
  padding: 20px;
}

table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>Navigation and Header</nav>
</header>
<main>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```