# Really long table goes out of a div. How to hide overflowing table without losing sticky elements inside of it?

Tags: html, css

I have **really long table**, and the table goes outside of the parent div. I could not change width of it to fit window size (parent width 100%).

If main has `overflow: hidden;`, it **makes important table sticky elements not `sticky`** and not scrollable horizontally.

It is also possible to make `.series__table_container` `overflow-x: scroll;`, it looks as i want it, **but `thead th` elements not sticky after it**.

Is there any possible way to hide overflown table content so it's not going outside of the main, making all html document wide, without loosing sticky elements at all?

```css
body {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}

.left-box {
  width: 15%;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.right-box {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.series__table_container {
  width: 100%;
}

.tables__wrapper-row {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.tr-names th {
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.tr-units th {
  background-color: green;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

tbody tr .tsl-check,
tbody tr .tsl-series {
  background-color: pink;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
        <div class="left-box">
        </div>
        <div class="right-box">
            <div class="series__table_container">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="tables__wrapper">
                        <div class="tables__wrapper-row">
                            <div class="series__table">
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="tr-names">
                                            <th class="tsl-check">
                                                <label class="check">
                                                    <input type="checkbox">
                                                    <span class="check_mark"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="tsl-series">Select All</th>
                                            <th colspan="6" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDQWE</th>
                                            <th colspan="1" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDQWE</th>
                                            <th colspan="10" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDQWE</th>
                                            <th colspan="2" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDQWE</th>
                                            <th colspan="1" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDQWE</th>
                                            <th colspan="5" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDQWE</th>
                                            <th colspan="13" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDQWE</th>
                                            <th colspan="4" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDQWE</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="tr-units">
                                            <th class="tsl-series" colspan="2"><strong>Section</strong></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">h<span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">b<span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">t<sub>w</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">t<sub>f</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">r<sub>1</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">d<span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">I<sub>y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">I<sub>z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">I<sub>p</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">i<sub>y</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">i<sub>z</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">i<sub>p</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">max S<sub>y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">max S<sub>z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">I<sub>t</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">max ω<span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">I<sub>ω</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>6</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">i<sub>ω</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>ω</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">max S<sub>ω</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>pl,y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>pl,z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>pl,ω</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">α<sub>pl,y</sub><span class="unit"> </span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">α<sub>pl,z</sub><span class="unit"> </span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">α<sub>pl,ω</sub><span class="unit"> </span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>pl,y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>pl,z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">N<sub>pl</sub><span class="unit">[kN]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">V<sub>pl,y</sub><span class="unit">[kN]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">V<sub>pl,z</sub><span class="unit">[kN]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">M<sub>pl,y</sub><span class="unit">[kNm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">M<sub>pl,z</sub><span class="unit">[kNm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">G<span class="unit">[kg/m]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>m</sub><span class="unit">[m<sup>2</sup>/m]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">V<span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>/m]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>m</sub>/V<span class="unit">[1/m]</span></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="" id="605">
                                            <td class="tsl-check">
                                                <label class="check">
                                                    <input type="checkbox">
                                                    <span class="check_mark"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-series active"><strong>qwe</strong><span class="sl-info-icon"> <a id="605" title="More info"> i </a></span></td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>127.0</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>76.0</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>4.0</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>7.6</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>7.6</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>96.6</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>16.50</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>473.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>56.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>529.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>53.5</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>18.4</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>56.6</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>42.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>5.50</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>75.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>15.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>9.79</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>4.82</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>2.85</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>22.69</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>2000.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>19.4</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>88.16</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>32.76</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>84.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>23.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>131.03</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>1.120</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>1.533</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>1.500</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>11.55</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>4.78</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>388.229</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>156.734</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>64.799</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>19.78</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>5.31</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>13.0</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>0.537</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>1650.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>325.426</a> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div> <!-- series__table -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="tables__wrapper-row">
                            <div class="series__table">
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="tr-names">
                                            <th class="tsl-check">
                                                <label class="check">
                                                    <input type="checkbox">
                                                    <span class="check_mark"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="tsl-series">Select All</th>
                                            <th colspan="6" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDASDASD</th>
                                            <th colspan="1" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDASDASD</th>
                                            <th colspan="10" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDASDASD</th>
                                            <th colspan="2" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDASDASD</th>
                                            <th colspan="1" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDASDASD</th>
                                            <th colspan="5" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDASDASD</th>
                                            <th colspan="13" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDASDASD</th>
                                            <th colspan="4" class="tsl-colgroup active">ASDQWE ASDASDASD</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="tr-units">
                                            <th class="tsl-series" colspan="2"><strong>Section</strong></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">h<span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">b<span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">t<sub>w</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">t<sub>f</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">r<sub>1</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">d<span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">I<sub>y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">I<sub>z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">I<sub>p</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">i<sub>y</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">i<sub>z</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">i<sub>p</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">max S<sub>y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">max S<sub>z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">I<sub>t</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">max ω<span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">I<sub>ω</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>6</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">i<sub>ω</sub><span class="unit">[mm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>ω</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">max S<sub>ω</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>pl,y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>pl,z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">W<sub>pl,ω</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>4</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">α<sub>pl,y</sub><span class="unit"> </span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">α<sub>pl,z</sub><span class="unit"> </span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">α<sub>pl,ω</sub><span class="unit"> </span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>pl,y</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>pl,z</sub><span class="unit">[cm<sup>2</sup>]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">N<sub>pl</sub><span class="unit">[kN]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">V<sub>pl,y</sub><span class="unit">[kN]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">V<sub>pl,z</sub><span class="unit">[kN]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">M<sub>pl,y</sub><span class="unit">[kNm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">M<sub>pl,z</sub><span class="unit">[kNm]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">G<span class="unit">[kg/m]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>m</sub><span class="unit">[m<sup>2</sup>/m]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">V<span class="unit">[cm<sup>3</sup>/m]</span></th>
                                            <th class="tsl-cell">A<sub>m</sub>/V<span class="unit">[1/m]</span></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="" id="605">
                                            <td class="tsl-check">
                                                <label class="check">
                                                    <input type="checkbox">
                                                    <span class="check_mark"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-series active"><strong>qwe</strong><span class="sl-info-icon"> <a id="605" title="More info"> i </a></span></td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>127.0</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>76.0</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>4.0</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>7.6</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>7.6</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>96.6</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>16.50</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>473.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>56.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell" style=""> <a>529.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>53.5</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>18.4</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>56.6</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>42.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>5.50</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>75.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>15.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>9.79</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>4.82</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>2.85</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>22.69</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>2000.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>19.4</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>88.16</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>32.76</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>84.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>23.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>131.03</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>1.120</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>1.533</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>1.500</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>11.55</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>4.78</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>388.229</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>156.734</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>64.799</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>19.78</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>5.31</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>13.0</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>0.537</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>1650.00</a> </td>
                                            <td class="tsl-cell"> <a>325.426</a> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                       
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div> <!-- series__table -->
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- tables__wrapper -->
                </div> <!-- container -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: would that fix your worry ? : `html {
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}` not sure i understood the question ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`overflow:hidden\` prevent \`position:sticky\` from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909940/why-does-overflowhidden-prevent-positionsticky-from-working)

Comment: @charles unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Possible **duplicate of [Why does `overflow:hidden` prevent `position:sticky` from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909940/why-does-overflowhidden-prevent-positionsticky-from-working)**

---

Sticky elements stick to the nearest ancestor with a scrolling mechanism. When you apply an `overflow` declaration to your `.main` element, this element becomes the scrolling ancestor.

This is a known issue. See issue on [w3c/csswg-drafts](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/865) (GitHub)

You can use JavaScript to achieve your intended effect.

- A solution from Dannie Vinther: [Position: stuck; — and a way to fix it](https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526) (UX Collective)
- A polyfill: [stickyfill](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill) (GitHub)