# overflow:auto doesn't work as expected with position:sticky

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have a bootstrap table with the bootstrap class of "table-responsive" as a result is sets overflow-x to auto for the times that the table is too wide for the screen.

i have also set the the th elements to the bootstrap class of  "sticky-top" which sets the position of the table th to sticky

as can be seen in this answer of the question [Why does `overflow:hidden` prevent `position:sticky` from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909940/why-does-overflowhidden-prevent-positionsticky-from-working) this is because when the parent of the sticky element is set to overflow it becomes the scrolling container for the element rather than the window

for now i have set table-responsive to overflow only if it is needed with a media query like so:

```
.table-responsive{
   overflow-x:inherit;
}

@media (max-width:432px){
   .table-responsive{
      overflow-x:auto;
   }
```

the issue is now that the table header doesn't stick on mobile screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve this issue i combined the script from [Rik Schennink](https://css-tricks.com/styling-based-on-scroll-position/) and [Dannie Vinther's approach](https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526).
in my case i created a copy of the table headers which is called "responsive-header"
this "Responsive-header" is set to `display:none` by default
when ever the original header scrolls out of view this responsive header is then made visible

here's a simplified version of what i have
HTML

```
<html>

  <body>
    <main>
      <section>
        <table id="respond" class='table table-responsive sticky-top responsive-header'>
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
        <table class='table table-responsive'>


          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
              <th class="sticky-top">sticky</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>test</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #212529;
}

.table .thead-dark th {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #343a40;
  border-color: #454d55;
}

.table-responsive {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.sticky-top {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1020;
}

.responsive-header {
  display: none;
}
```

and jQuery

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {

  var timeout;

  return function() {

    var context = this,
      args = arguments;

    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;

      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);

    };

    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);

  };

}

const storeScroll = () => {
  document.documentElement.dataset.scroll = window.scrollY;
  if (window.scrollY >= 10) $('#respond').removeClass('responsive-header');
  else $('#respond').addClass('responsive-header');
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(storeScroll), {
  passive: true
});
// Update scroll position for first time                                                                                                                                                    @
storeScroll();
```

and the jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/uf468ocy/