# How can I use sticky positioning in a container with hidden overflow?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with `position: sticky`. This is my html distribution:

[HTML distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA1c2.png)

```
.A {overflow:hidden;}
.C {height: 500px;}
.D {height: 100px; position: sticky;}
```

I found in blogs that `position: sticky` doesn't work when the direct parent of the element has the `overflow: hidden` property. But, in this case, there is more than one level between class "A" and "D" elements. I also try to force the `overflow: visible` property to the class "C" element, but sticky still not working in "D".

Comment: I think you'll find that you're more likely to be understood if you don't try to speak in code. :)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you can use the code-snippet-tool to add an executable version of your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`overflow:hidden\` prevent \`position:sticky\` from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909940/why-does-overflowhidden-prevent-positionsticky-from-working)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't,
Position : sticky doesn't work with a parent which got overflow set.

If you really need this, you should use Javascript with a on scroll event toggling position

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately using the `position: sticky` property with a parent element that is `overflow: hidden` will not work.

If you must have a parent element be `overflow: hidden` then you will most likely have to use JavaScript with some scrolling/viewport visible functions or preferably `IntersectionObserver API`.

If you have some flexibility and can move some of the HTML around, there may be a solution where you can put the element you want with `position: sticky` outside of that `overflow: hidden` element and have it be in the same place.

EDIT: I remember providing a similar answer about using `position: sticky` and wanted to share the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/treckstar/d30phae8/13/) that I helped someone with. All the pre-existing markup is in the `HTML` section and the updates I suggested to get it working are in the `CSS` section.